# How to duplicate rows and make multiple inserts for each row for a specific column using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

Is there a way in SQL to duplicate each row and and enter a constant value before each result as shown:

```
This is what I have:

    Name        Height            
1   John        6.5         
2   Ben         7.0         
3   Mike        6.6
4   Adam        7.1
```

I want to add new row infront of each row in the data and specify values (ex. 1, 5, 5, 5….) as seen below:

```
    Name        Height            
1   JohnStart   1
2   John        6.5
3   BenStart    5                       
4   Ben         7.0
5   MikeStart   5                       
6   Mike        6.6
7   AdamStart   5
8   Adam        7.1
```

I have tried the insert function but it’s not working

```
INSERT INTO mydata (Name, Height)
VALUES ('AdamStart', '5')
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "in front of each row".  What is the first column?

Comment: First column is name

Comment: what is criteria for the new value?

Comment: There is no criteria, I have to add another row and pick a constant for graphing purposes. I am not sure if this is doable

Comment: Is there a formula or a pattern to determine what height to set for each start?  like use the numbers 1-5 in name order then start over or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL UNION operator to do the same.  Also, (Abs(Checksum(NewId())) % 10) generates a GUI internally, calculates the absolute value of its checksum. It will always generate a value between 0 and 10. Added 1 to handle the zero value case.

```
SELECT Name, Height FROM tbl
UNION
SELECT Name + 'Start', (Abs(Checksum(NewId())) % 10) + 1 FROM tbl
```

Comment: Do you have another table or table variable to store that detail

Comment: Thank you, that is getting somewhere but unfortunately as @LONG mentioned not all come with the 5. after 4 or 5 rows I want to enter 1 again.

Comment: That's what i asked, do you have any table variable that stores the names and values you want to insert with it

Comment: No I don't, i just have that one table

Comment: You can use random number but it can return 0 sometimes. Added 1 so that 0 condition is handled.